# Tilings of the Hyperbolic plane

Tags: graph-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

Given a tiling of the hyperbolic plane projected onto a unit disc such as [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/1/13/20130706023453%21Uniform_tiling_433-t0.png) which can be considered as a graph. I then define some functions:

$f(r) =$ number of graph nodes contained within the a radius $r$ from the centre

$g(r) =$ number of graph edges connecting  a node within a radius $r$ of the centre to one outside a radius $r$ from the centre

and the limiting ratio
$$c = \lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \frac{g(r)}{f(r)}$$
In the case of the link given I think the 2-in-4-out structure of the graph means that $c=2$. Is this correct? Is there a simple way of 'reading off' this limiting ratio in the case of projections of [more general tilings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane) particularly those lacking the useful symmetries of the one considered here.

Comment: I do not know much about this, but the constant $c$ you defined is a form of the *Cheeger constant* of a graph.

Comment: Ah thanks very much! A bit of looking around the literature on the _Cheeger constant_ suggests that $h$ is given by $h = \min_r \frac{g(r)}{f(r)}$, but it does also seem to suggest that the exponential geometry of hyperbolic tilings means that the limit given above does converge.

Comment: If I remember correctly, inf is the same as lim in this setting.

Comment: Do you mean to say that taking $min_r$ gives the same as taking $lim_{r\rightarrow 1}$?

Comment: I think so, except it is inf instead of min.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I understand now.